# How can I get the ID of the inserted record?

Tags: php, mysql

I had tried to find last inserted id in php, but I am unable to get.
It displays value 0.

This is my code:

```
require_once "../config.php"; 

$query = "call experience_insert('$uid','$title','$cname','$sdate','$edt')";

$result = $connection->ServerDb->query($query);
$id = $connection->ServerDb->insert_id;
```

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you when nobody has any idea what `$connection->ServerDb` is?

Comment: check lastInsertId() http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post the relevant sections of the stored procedure you're calling. It should have a `return` statement that gives back the ID. Keep in mind there are weird gotchas with MySQL stored procedures and `last_insert_id()` as well.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines-last-insert-id.html